# How do I make this jQuery script running after all page content it's been loaded?

Tags: jquery

I am asking because I have 3 anchor links supposed to smooth scroll to their section but the last one works properly only on firefox... on Safari and mobile the last link jumps back a little so I think the reason is that the page isn't fully loaded when the event is triggered, causing this annoying problem (I am having the same problem even while using other jQuery solutions)...

This is the code:

```
// Select all links with hashes
$('a[href*="#"]')
  // Remove links that don't actually link to anything
  .not('[href="#"]')
  .not('[href="#0"]')
  .click(function(event) {
    // On-page links
    if (
      location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') 
      && 
      location.hostname == this.hostname
    ) {
      // Figure out element to scroll to
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      // Does a scroll target exist?
      if (target.length) {
        // Only prevent default if animation is actually gonna happen
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000, function() {
          // Callback after animation
          // Must change focus!
          var $target = $(target);
          $target.focus();
          if ($target.is(":focus")) { // Checking if the target was focused
            return false;
          } else {
            $target.attr('tabindex','-1'); // Adding tabindex for elements not focusable
            $target.focus(); // Set focus again
          };
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Do some research before asking a question here. $(document).ready() is really basic knowledge... apart from that, only use the related tags. in this case jQuery

Comment: [learn jquery doc.ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: @GertB. I have tried this....the script won't work...